# I own Pokémon Y, and Alpha Sapphire. Which ones (barring Friend Safari) will I still have to trade?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I own both Pokemon Y and Alpha Sapphire. My goal is to use AS mostly to catch Pokémon I can't get on Y, and then transferring them to there using the Pokébank. The friend safari in Y is also a huge help to be able to get types I couldn't get otherwise.

Going from these facts, and the assumption I could get any Pokémon family available in the friend safari through codes and then breeding them, for which ones do I still have to trade?

Answer (score 2):

According to a spreadsheet I've made for myself to answer a similar question you will need to trade for those non-mythical Pokémon:

- Houndour
- Houndoom (or evolve Houndour)
- Ho-Oh
- Groudon
- Palkia
- Tornadus
- Reshiram
- Xerneas